# Filed is optional in ms-crm but showing mandatory in powerportal case creation! How?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Can anyone help me with the problem, field is showing mandatory in ms-crm powerportal but it is optional in ms-crm

Comment: please check if there is any custom javascript attache to your powerportal case creation form? In addition is your portals from same as you are looking into crm?

Comment: No Javascript is attached in the case creation. and yes I am in the same portal as in ms-crm. Please help its urgent.

Comment: add some screenshot of your portals forms, same from in customization mode and also what exact error/Issue you face again screenshot.

Comment: I am unable to attach the screenshot here, you can imagine the red dot mark on invoice field in the portal and back in the customization in ms-crm the red dot mark is not there.